# VbScript to trim trailing pipes off file at 35 pipes

Tags: windows, vba, vbscript, windows-scripting

So I was initially writing this in batch, but the number of tokens usable with ASCII were too small, i guess it only allows 26, and I need 35 pipes to remain in my output file.

I am new to VBScript, but basically I want it to read in the original file, do some magic to select the first character in the file to the last 35 pipes (and everything between, even in the space between the two pipes is blank). Then output that file to another file, while retaining the integrity of original.

Here is my code so far:

```
' **************
' ** Anthony B.
' **************
' ** PipeDropper
' **************
Dim WshShell, oExec
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objInputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\aborgetti\Desktop\Pipe Delimiter Project\oauthrn.cms",1)
Set objOutputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\aborgetti\Desktop\Pipe Delimiter Project\output.txt",8,True)

Do until objInputFile.AtEndofStream
    strcomputer = objInputFile.ReadLine
    strCommand = "dsquery computer -name " & strComputer
    Set oExec = WShShell.Exec(strCommand)
    If (oExec.Status = 0) Then
        If (oExec.stdOut.ReadAll = "") Then
            objOutputFile.WriteLine(strComputer)
        End If
    End If
Loop

objInputFile.Close
objOutputFile.Close
```

**Issues**

This line `Set oExec = WShShell.Exec(strCommand)`
says it can't find the file that's specified...so I'm not sure why that's bad.

And then where do I go from here?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Here is a line that would be in the file, usually anywhere from 10-100 times...

```
RE|922124607|1 |KimV|HOS99999|Y|N|2014-04-02 15:49:14|2014-04-02 15:49:58|Y|2014-04-02 00:00:00|R9815|01|1 |2014-04-02 00:00:00|493.90||||2016-04-02|N||HOS99999|||06|PROV99999|2014-04-02 15:48:20|2014-04-02||R9815|2014-04-02 00:00:00|2016-04-02 00:00:00||||||98960|06 |08|6|6|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||02|||||||Z4|2014-04-02 15:49:58|04|001|01|***|PMER|***|***|2013-08-01||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

Everything after the last 01 needs to go...so:

```
|***|PMER|***|***|2013-08-01||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

Should be:

```
Start of line ...  |***|PMER|***|***|2013-08-01
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what a line looks like & what would you like to extract of it?

Comment: i don't see anything in the above that is even attempting to test a character to see if it is a pipe. You are 90% there...keep going. You read the line so instead loop through the line (or instead just read a character) and check if each character is a pipe, incrementing a counter as you go.

Comment: Also from your second question, I don't see how that relates to the first? That has nothing to do with the number of "|" characters read so far. If it is failing then it is to do with the command passed in, or rather whatever "strComputer" is meant to be for the dquery command vs. what is being passed in.

Comment: @Cor_Blimey See my update...I know I haven't even really read in the line, but I am interested in doing so...thanks for your input and time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that your problem

1. has anything to do with pipes
2. the code you published is the code that caused the error

There are two ways to get an error 424 "Object required" for a statement like

```
Set a = b.c(d)
```

The first (and obvious): b isn't an object. The second: the return value of b.c(d) isn't an object.

Your code condensed:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCommand = "hostname"
Set oExec = WShShell.Exec(strCommand)
WScript.Echo oExec.Stdout.Readline()
```

runs without a problem. A slight change:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCommand = "hostname"
Set oExec = WShShel1.Exec(strCommand)
WScript.Echo oExec.Stdout.Readline()
```

fails with "Object required". Do you spot the typo? Why not let "Option Explicit" help you:

```
Option Explicit
Dim wshShell   : Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim strCommand : strCommand = "hostname"
Dim oExec      : Set oExec = WShShel1.Exec(strCommand)
WScript.Echo oExec.Stdout.Readline()
```

output:

```
...\22871772.vbs(4, 18) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Variable is undefined: 'WShShel1'
```

If you made sure that no typo caused the problem, you'll have to check whether the variable is changed/assigned to between initialization and use:

```
Option Explicit
Dim wshShell   : Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim strCommand : strCommand = "hostname"
'...
wShSheLL = "oops"
'...
Dim oExec      : Set oExec = WShShell.Exec(strCommand)
WScript.Echo oExec.Stdout.Readline()
```

again fails with error 424.

Update wrt the [pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22863616/603855):

I'd choose [Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) (with count set to #pipes you want + 1) to deal with the trailing pipes:

```
>> n = 8 + 1
>> s = "|abc123|1*|004|**gobbligook|001|%|2014-01-01|||||||||||||"
>> a = Split(s, "|", n)  ' <-- 9th elm get all the junk
>> WScript.Echo UBound(a)
>> a(n - 1) = "" ' <-- zap the junk
>> WScript.Echo Join(a, "|")
>>
8
|abc123|1*|004|**gobbligook|001|%|2014-01-01|
```

To delete a tail of |'s, a RegExp seems more appropriate:

```
>> set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "\|+$"
>> WScript.Echo r.Replace(s, "")
>>
|abc123|1*|004|**gobbligook|001|%|2014-01-01
```

Comment: great answer, except I am not so sure about the use of Split. What if say the last batch of 23 pipes (out of the 35 pipe batches specified) falls within the...the last batch? The question didn't seem to just be about a single 'trailing' pipe. I think it might be better to use `Stream.Read` to read through each character testing and incrementing a pipe counter appropriately. However, 2/3rds of your answer is golden and a really good example of why `Option Explicit` shouldn't be an 'Option' at all.

Comment: edit: I think the first part of the question seems to be about pipes but after the OP's code it seems to be about something else completely. So +1 for making head or tail of it ;)

Comment: The code is the way it is because I've never coded A VBscript before. Today was the first day I even ran a VBscript. My code is my preliminary run at getting vb to do something. Although it's not at this time relevant to the pipe question the pipe issue is what I ultimately want the code to do. Thanks